# Denied insert statement in before update trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to create a history table. In the case of an update I want to be able to select the "old" data and move it to the delta table. Therefore i created the following trigger:

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists  entity_url_before_update_to_delta;
create trigger entity_url_before_update_to_delta
before update on entity_url
for each row
   begin
      insert into delta.entity_url 
      (url_id, updated_at, title, description, h1, h2, content, main_entity, 
      entity_sentence_id, entity_id) 
      values(old.url_id, old.updated_at, old.title, old.description, old.h1, old.h2, 
      old.content, old.main_entity, old.entity_sentence_id, old.entity_id);
   end $$
delimiter ;
```

However when an update statement is fired the database gives the following error: 
"Error code 1142. Insert command denied to users "user@..." for table entity_url".
Is this due to using an insert statement in an update trigger or because i do not have the proper rights for this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is because you do not have the proper permissions.

Comment: Thanks, how can i grant this to myself? Because when i run the command: SHOW GRANTS, it says all privileges.

Comment: . . Is the `insert` into the same table?  That doesn't seem like a good idea.  Otherwise, the issue is with permissions on `delta.entity_url`.

Comment: The insert is on another table which stores the historical data. So the cause must be the priviliges. Thanks, i'm going to look into this problem.